# Nativescript-dom typescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am a newbie in to the nativescript framework I wanna tryout some stuffs then I stumbled upon the this plugin now I dont know how to use it with typescript

```
TypeError: page.getElementById is not a function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukg9e.png)
Here is error I get.
Attached is my code screen shot

Comment: So you used page.getViewById, and all of a sudden you started using `getElementById`? Is that a clue enough?

Comment: Also, note that you have several views with the same id, this will be a problem when trying to find the right view.

Comment: Yes!  this is where I've got problem because I need to to use multiple items with the same ID, that lead me in to the use of nativescript-dom plugin

Comment: I believe having different views with the same id is wrong. Consider using a common 'class' instead.

Comment: using the same class how do I select them together and change hidden class on all of the items

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for on a View instance is `getViewById` which allows you to get a child view by its id.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#execute-business-logic

Comment: Thanks @pkanev, have you worked with Nativescript-dom plugin using typescript?